# Understanding scope and *args and **kwargs in decorator function

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

Why is it that the `wrapper()` function needs `*args` and `**kwargs` in the decorator example below?

```
def currency(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return '$' + str(f(*args, **kwargs))

    return wrapper

class Product(db.Model):

    name = db.StringColumn
    price = db.FloatColumn

    @currency
    def price_with_tax(self, tax_rate_percentage):
        """Return the price with *tax_rate_percentage* applied.
        *tax_rate_percentage* is the tax rate expressed as a float, like "7.0"
        for a 7% tax rate."""
        return price * (1 + (tax_rate_percentage * .01))
```

Aren't the arguments passed to `price_with_tax(self, tax_rate_percentage)` already available in the scope of the `def currency(f)` function and thus available to the `wrapper()` function?

Why can't we just pass `f()` right into `wrapper()` ?

I'm just trying to understand why `wrapper()` has `*args` and `**kwargs` and how both are each getting the arguments passed to `price_with_tax(self, tax_rate_percentage)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wrapper takes a function as an argument and returns another function. In order for that returned function to be as useful as possible (i.e., applied to any function or method), it must accept any number of arguments.

Consider what a decorator does. This:

```
@currency
def price_with_tax(self, tax_rate_percentage):
    return price * (1 + (tax_rate_percentage * .01))
```

Is essentially just shorthand for this:

```
def price_with_tax(self, tax_rate_percentage):
    return price * (1 + (tax_rate_percentage * .01))
price_with_tax = currency(price_with_tax)
```

That is, `price_with_tax` is, ultimately, the return value of `currency`, so it should also be a function that takes at least two arguments (`self` and `tax_rate_percentage`).

However, `@currency` could be used to decorate a lot of other functions which may take different numbers of args and different keyword arguments, so decorators like `currency` often take variable arguments to handle all cases.